# React nested route is not changing

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

Im trying to create some routes inside of my dashboard but Im having some dificcult, My project has a root page where it has route for /admin it`s working fine, inside of the admin page Im using the same code with /home but it`s not working (to access /admin/home).. that is my code:

root:

```
render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
        <Navigation authUser={this.state.authUser} />

          <Route
            exact path={routes.ADMIN}
            component={AdminPage}
          />
        </div>
      </Route>
```

admin:
     render() {
    const { users } = this.props;

```
return (
  <div>
    <Switch>
      <Route
        exact path={routes.ADMIN_HOME}
        component={AdmHomePage}
      />

    </Switch>

  </div>
```

route.ADMIN_HOME == '/home'

route.ADMIN == '/admin'

Comment: witch react-router version are you using?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the entire path for sub-routes including the parent path.

e.g. route.ADMIN_HOME should be `/admin/home`

Also it is important the parent route does not include the exact prop. This is because the parent route won't render unless it's exactly `/admin` so it will never render the routes within the parent component.

I've attached an runnable example below. Note; I've switched out BrowserRouter for HashRouter so that it runs on StackOverflow.

```js
const HashRouter = ReactRouterDOM.HashRouter;
const Route = ReactRouterDOM.Route;
const Link = ReactRouterDOM.Link;
const Switch = ReactRouterDOM.Switch;

const Players = () => (
  <div>
    <h5>Players</h5>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/players/joe" render={() => <div>Joe</div>} />
      <Route path="/players/emily" render={() => <div>Emily</div>} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <HashRouter>
    <div>
      <h5>Navigation</h5>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/players">Players</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/players/joe">Players - Joe</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/players/emily">Players - Emily</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
      </ul>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/players" component={Players} />
        <Route path="/about" render={() => <div>About Page</div>} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </HashRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router-dom/umd/react-router-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```